# Render a component multiple times React.js

Tags: reactjs, web, rendering

This is a code for a simple counter.

However, when i Render the view i don't get any output. Please tell me what is wrong with the code.

The button is pressed and a counter is incremented and is rendered onto the screen.

```
 var Title = React.createClass({

  getInitialState : function(){
    return {count:0};
  },
  increment : function(){

    this.setState({count:this.state.count+this.props.incVal});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 >Count : {this.state.count}< /h1>
        <button onClick={this.increment} >Increment</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
});




var MultiButton = React.createClass({
  render : function (){
    return(
      <Title incVal={1}/>
      <Title incVal={5}/>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render( <MultiButton /> ,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

Comment: Besides the correct answer by Rafael below, react does show nice error messages in to the browser console (opened by pressing `F12` in most browsers). Might be a good practice to look at error logs in your browser console when something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot return more than one elements from the React class. If you have more than one elements wrap them in a single div like

```
var MultiButton = React.createClass({
  render : function (){
    return(
      <div>
          <Title incVal={1}/>
          <Title incVal={5}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [official documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html).

```
<div>
  Here is a list:
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

> A React component can't return multiple React elements, but a single
>   JSX expression can have multiple children, so if you want a component
>   to render multiple things you can wrap it in a div like this.

Change from

```
var MultiButton = React.createClass(
  {
    render: function () {
      return (
        <Title incVal={1}/>
        <Title incVal={5}/>
      );
    }
  }  
);
```

to

```
var MultiButton = React.createClass(
  {
    render: function () {
      return (
        <div>
          <Title incVal={1}/>
          <Title incVal={5}/>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }  
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var Title = React.createClass({

  getInitialState : function(){
    return {count:0};
  },
  increment : function(){

    this.setState({count:this.state.count+this.props.incVal});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 >Count : {this.state.count}< /h1>
        <button onClick={this.increment.bind(this)} >Increment</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
});




var MultiButton = React.createClass({
  render : function (){
    return(
      <Title incVal={1}/>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render( <MultiButton /> ,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```